# impala shell output csv file generation with enclosure

Tags: sql, shell, impala

I am new to Impala. I am trying to fetch data from a table and load it to csv file. But I want to enclose the data in double quotes as there is a conflict in delimiter. How can I enclose the data with double quotes for each field?

```
query = "select t1max,t2max,rest_call from topo_tax"

result_string = 'env -i /usr/bin/impala-shell -i "'+ impalad+':'+port +'" -u "'+user+'" -d "'+database+'" -B --delimited -q "'+query+'"' ' -o /tmp/data_dump.csv --print_header --output_delimiter=,'
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you might give delimiter as ","